How to fix YAML_FILE_ERROR. Download_source State: failed
Running on CodeBuild On-demand
Waiting for agent ping
Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src2136787222/src
YAML location is /codebuild/output/src2136787222/src/buildspec.yml
DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED
Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: did not find expected key at line 15

buildspec.yml
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 16
    commands:
      - echo Entering dashboardclient directory
      - cd dashboardclient
      - echo Installing frontend dependencies
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Building frontend
      - npm run build
   post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Frontend build complete
      - echo Listing contents of dashboardclient directory
      - ls -la  # Check current directory
      - ls -la dashboardclient  # Check contents of dashboardclient directory
      - echo Listing contents of build directory
      - ls -la dashboardclient/dist  # Check contents of build directory

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: 'dashboardclient/dist'


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Did the answer below helped you solve your problem?

YAML is not properly indented at line 16 (post_build).
Fixed YAML:
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 16
    commands:
      - echo Entering dashboardclient directory
      - cd dashboardclient
      - echo Installing frontend dependencies
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Building frontend
      - npm run build
    post_build:
      commands:
        - echo Frontend build complete
        - echo Listing contents of dashboardclient directory
        - ls -la  # Check current directory
        - ls -la dashboardclient  # Check contents of dashboardclient directory
        - echo Listing contents of build directory
        - ls -la dashboardclient/dist  # Check contents of build directory

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: 'dashboardclient/dist'

